# Defining vars for database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have worked with MySQL before but it has been a LONG time ago. Now I am trying to set up a database using phpMyAdmin.

I am trying to setup this database for the Article Friendly script. The instructions state that you need to use a little script that they have furnished:

```
define("DB_NAME","a6852953_article");
define("SERVER_NAME","'mysql12.000webhost.com'");
define("USER_NAME","a6852953_article");
define("PASSWORD","*********");
$dbhost=SERVER_NAME;
$dbuser=USER_NAME;
$dbpasswd=PASSWORD;
$dbname=DB_NAME;
```

It chokes on the first line, and if I remove that it chokes on whatever is there.

The syntax looks correct to me with what little I remember and I also checked the manual for 5.1 which is what my host uses.

Can anyone spot anything wrong?

Comment: Well the first thing I spotted, that is wrong - you just gave out your database credentials.

Comment: this script is obviously php. With more of the contextual elements we will certainly help.

Comment: whats with the redundancy? `$dbhost=SERVER_NAME` just use `SERVER_NAME` rather then wasting memory allocating the same data twice

Comment: Do you have anything before that first line you showed?

Comment: what message do you get when it chokes? do you have any additional logged message in php_errors file?

Comment: Looks like phpnoob saved your database for you! Now i suggest changing your password from what you displayed! :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might actually be choking on the second line...

```
define("SERVER_NAME","'mysql12.000webhost.com'");
```

... likely because you have single quotes inside the double quotes. Try changing the line to this:

```
define("SERVER_NAME","mysql12.000webhost.com");
```

If it *is* the first line however, make sure that the database you listed already exists -- if not, you should be able to login to phpMyAdmin and run:

```
CREATE DATABASE a6852953_article
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies everyone!  Let me see if I can get through this one at a time.....  David these are NOT my credentials but are just for an example that follows the same syntax.  This is the complete script that I am using through phpMyAdmin.  I have removed the single quotes, that was actually the first thing I did but put them back after the errors.  The db does exist I created that before I did anything else....

Comment: Oh and the only error I get is a generic syntax error that shows in the browser.  I am not seeing anything in the error log which seems strange to me but it just shows that there is a syntax error there also.

Comment: Hmm... Well, like @Sebas pointed out, this appears to be a PHP script as opposed to something you would use while logged into phpMyAdmin. The code itself *would* definitely be something you'd place inside a PHP file in order for the program to connect to the database, but trying to run this code directly inside PMA would (and should) fail. So it sounds to me like the code needs to placed inside a file on your server somewhere (for example, inside `database.php` or `config.php` or something). Did they tell you where to add the code? Or if not, can you ask them?